# Okta GroupUsersClient Class Not Adding Users Consistantly and No Error Message

Tags: .net, sdk, okta

We developed a .NET Console application to add Applications, Groups and Users.  In the same application we have methods to add Groups -> Apps and Users -> Groups.  We found that the user is not always added to the specified Group as expected.  When it happens we do not receive an error message.

We are using the Okta .NET SDK v4.0.30319.  Below is the method we execute to add the user to a group.  Has anyone come across this issue and if so, how did you resolve it?

```
static List<string> OktaAddGroupUser(string sGroupName, string sLogin, Okta.Core.Clients.GroupsClient groupsClient, Okta.Core.Clients.UsersClient usersClient, string strOktaToken, string strOktaSubdomain)
    {
        List<string> arrayReturn = new List<string>();
        Okta.Core.PagedResults<Group> oktaGroups;
        Okta.Core.Clients.GroupUsersClient oktaGroupUsersClient;

        try
        {
            var oktaUser = usersClient.Get(sLogin);
            oktaGroups = groupsClient.GetList();

            foreach (var oktaGroup in oktaGroups.Results) 
            {
                if (oktaGroup.Profile.Name.ToString() == sGroupName)
                {
                    oktaGroupUsersClient = new Okta.Core.Clients.GroupUsersClient(oktaGroup, strOktaToken, "ogletree");
                    oktaGroupUsersClient.Add(oktaUser);
                }
            }

            arrayReturn.Add("0");
            arrayReturn.Add("OktaAddUserGroup: User successfully added to group");
        }
        catch (Okta.Core.OktaException e)
        {
            arrayReturn.Add(e.ErrorCode.ToString());
            arrayReturn.Add("OktaAddUserGroup: " + e.Message.ToString());
        }

        return arrayReturn;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you have more than 200 groups (and generally speaking more than 200 Okta items in your Okta tenant).

Indeed, when you call the GetList() method, a default page size of 200 is applied (if you don't override the pageSize parameter) so that GetList() call will only return the first 200 items it finds.

The GetList() method supports optional parameters such as the "query" and "filter" parameters that can be used to perform a more optimal query and avoid unnecessary loops.

In your specific case, because you're only interested in retrieving a particular group with a specific name, you should use a GetList(query: sGroupName) call. This should return a PageResults object with one single object in its Results property (at most! the group also might not exist).

Doing a GetList(query: "somevalue") will translate into a "?q=somevalue" parameter added to your REST query. When calling the Groups API, the query will be something like {{url}}/api/v1/groups?limit=200&q=somevalue, which you can easily test in Postman (cf. http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/api_test_client.html)

I hope this helps!